# Dividing long paragraphs across pages

Tags: wrapping

By default, vim will not split long paragraphs (or any paragraphs (= long lines)) across pages. Instead of showing the first part of a paragraph that does not fit into the page entirely, it leaves out all of it, even if this leaves half the screen empty. Can this be changed?

As an example, see how line 1 is followed by a blank area as line 2 is too big to fit:

[image]
[image]

PS. I answered this quæstion myself below, but the result is still not quite as I want it. The remaining problem is that, when one scrolls with `<ctrl-e>` and `<ctrl-y>`, vim will only allow the first display line of a paragraph to be at the top of the screen. I want it to be possible to put any display line on top of the screen with `<ctrl-e>` and `<ctrl-y>`. This would be parallel to `gj` and `gk`.

Comment: You mean, like the `gj`/`gk` motion, or something else?

Comment: By “paragraph”, do you mean sequences of non-empty lines? Or do you in fact mean lines? And by pages, do you mean screen pages, or sequences of characters other than form feed, or what?

Comment: I think you're talking about lines (as opposed to sentences). A paragraph is a different thing. Calling a very long line a paragraph is very confusing.

Comment: @muru: What thing is a paragraph then? It seems to me that a paragraph my well be regarded as a long broken line, as I indicated in my parenthesis.

Comment: @Lawrence that's the literary paragraph, which is vague, and hence not very useful for programming an editor. Vim's notion of a paragraph is given in [`:h paragraph`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#paragraph) (essentially a block of text demarcated by blank lines).

Comment: does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15124386/gvim-what-do-the-symbols-mean-at-the-bottom-left-of-the-screen/15124555#15124555